# How to specify dates when retrieving a stocktwits stream

Tags: stream, symbols, stocktwits

I am retrieving streams from the https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/streams/symbol/:id.json endpoint, but so far I have been getting the latest 30 posts. I'm wondering if it's possible to specify a date in the past to get posts for that date, or a range of dates.